# Just lost electrical power to 1/2 of two rooms, on separate circuits?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, electrical-panel

Flipped the light switch for my laundry room, bulb flashed and now I lost partial power in that room and in the garage. No breakers tripped. Cycling them doesn't help. Panel and all switches is 2 years old. There are no GFCIs involved anywhere.

My laundry room is sort of a "bonus room," with a light switch in an adjacent room. When you flip the light switch it turns on the light for the laundry room and the garage. The laundry room has x3 wall outlets, the garage has a couple as well. Power to the wall outlets is not controlled by the light switch.

However, now the laundry room light, garage light and one laundry room outlet no longer have power. Just to repeat, this outlet is not controlled by the light switch. The other outlets in the laundry room still have power, as do the ones in the garage. None of the breakers in the box have tripped. I've cycled every single one anyway, with no effect, still not getting power to the lights or that single outlet.

What happened here? Some sort of a short? Why wouldn't the breaker have tripped? Why would it be affecting an outlet not tied to the switch?
[image: Panel]

Comment: The fact that a garage is involved points to a GFCI that you haven't discovered yet. When was the home built?

Comment: @isherwood "Panel and all switches is 2 years old." - So there should be GFCI and AFCI in there somewhere.

Comment: Otherwise I'd suspect a poor connection exacerbated by the flash/surge. You might have to start checking devices for loose screws and cheap backstab clamps.

Comment: @isherwood Home was built in the 60s, no GFCIs anywhere. House came this way.

Comment: @manassehkatz  "Panel and all switches is 2 years old." By switches I meant in the panel itself. I had it upgraded to a larger unit from the original when I bought new kitchen appliances 2 years ago. There are no GFCI receptacles anywhere in the house though.

Comment: Some of those breakers may - actually **should** - have GFCI built in. Can you post a picture of the panel/breakers?

Comment: As isherwood stated the flash may have been caused by the filament in the light creating a direct short. Many times daisy chained circuits use back stabs the push in connectors on the outlets or switches if just 1 of these connections failed in the chain on the hot or neutral everything after that point would no longer work. The problem can usually be found at the last working device in the line or first non working device, this is very common with back stabbed circuits that have been overloaded and the stab may have failed prior to the breaker tripping.

Comment: @EdBeal None of the outlets in either room currently have anything plugged into them. One of the outlets has no power, the rest do. These outlets aren't controlled by the switch for the lights that also lost power. Does it make sense that one of these outlets would lose power if the problem is somewhere in the seemingly unrelated lights/switch?

Comment: You could easily have a cable from one breaker that chains to several outlets and after the last outlet chain to the light switches - or possibly split off to multiple light switches. In that case, one bad outlet (either the one that is currently "out", or the one right before it) could easily be the problem as @EdBeal described with backstabs.

Comment: @manassehkatz In that case I suppose that rather than one bad outlet, it could be the ancient ceiling fan/light in the laundry room (the one that flashed) that is busting the circuit? I've been meaning to take that thing down for ages. If I just unwire the fan, should the restore the circuit if it was the culprit? Or would I likely need to wire something else in its place?

Comment: A switched fan/light should not have any effect on an unswitched item (the bad outlet), **unless** it a short that caused the entire circuit to not work - which would happen if it caused the breaker to trip. If you have ruled out any breakers having tripped then my suggestion is to: (a) Identify the breaker that is connected to all of this stuff and turn it off; (b) check EVERY outlet that is connected to that breaker (including the currently bad outlet) and move any backstabs to screws, check for (and tighten) loose wires, check for any sizes of arcing, etc. Then turn on the breaker and test.

Comment: Are you sure this is on two separate circuits?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel No, I just assume so since the switch doesn't control the outlet that also lost power

Answer (score 1):

This is getting two long for comments.

I usually figure out the location using the main panel as a starting point, we normally run as little wire as possible so if the chain in this case went to a fan/light there could be a pig tail that failed but this would be rare thogh possible.

One of your outlets that was not controlled by the switch is now dead (this may be the failure point) With the string of outlets on that circuit one probably feeds the light but the problem may be 5 outlets closer to the main panel - it just depends where the connection was lost.

I usually start closest to the breaker panel and start checking until I find a dead outlet. I pull that outlet and check it for damage. If I don't see any damage then I pull the one prior, just realize that if a common wall between 2 rooms there are outlets in the other room that are probably on the same circuit.

Once I find the last working outlet and the first dead one, the problem is almost always there. Now if you don't find any damage to the wires in those 2 locations, turn the breaker back on and if the circuit now works the back-stab reconnected and since you don't know the flakey outlet, replace both or at least rewire them using the screw terminals (with the power off ).

To tell the truth, I hate back stabs but they have made me thousands of $ to repair this exact problem some times caused by hair dryers, vacuum cleaners, electric heaters, and yes shorted light bulbs. So go back and find the first dead outlet, if not there it could be the feed from the last working outlet.

This will pinpoint the failure since some outlets are working. No fancy equipment needed, just observation and a screwdriver. So yes this makes total sense because the weakest back stab in the link failed and it could be the hot or neutral.